# What is the difference between 'Conditionals' & 'Subjunctive mood'?

Tags: conditional-constructions, subjunctives

Do both conditionals and Subjunctive mood overlap each other at some point or are they just different concepts?

For example: **If we started now we would be in time.** (subjunctive mood)

The above sentence is also a 2nd type conditional. So I was wondering, what is the difference between both concepts ?

Comment: I started answering, but then realized that I wasn't answering the question asked...  Sorry.  I think the answer is that Second Conditionals are formed using *subjunctive mood* of the verb, which is either a special form of the word (like '*were*' even for singular '*to be*') or '*would*'+infinitive.  That's the relationship between them.  Just different concepts.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. That sentence is a 2nd type conditional, thus it is about the present/near future, and the conditions are unlikely to be/become true. There isn't really any other possible interpretation. Also Modern English doesn't really have a subjunctive mood, aside from the "If I were" idiom.

Answer (score 5):

To answer your questions:

1. Do both conditionals and subjunctive mood overlap each other at some point?

   ***Yes, they do. Both the second and third conditional overlap with the subjunctive mood and its unreal state.***
2. What is the difference between a second or third conditional and subjunctive mood?

   ***While second and third conditionals are only capable of expressing unreal states in the present and the past, respectively; the subjunctive can further express such things as a wish, emotion, opinion, obligation, importance, and so on.***

These descriptions can be a bit daunting to parse, so let's take your example and demonstrate them.

- First Conditional 
   *If we start now, we'll be on time.*
- Second Conditional (also, subjunctive possibility) 
   *If we were in a faster car, we would be on time.*
- Third Conditional (also, subjunctive possibility) 
   *If we had started earlier, we would have been on time.*
- Subjunctive (importance) 
   *It is imperative that we make it on time.*
- Subjunctive (wish) 
   *I wish we had started already.*
- Subjunctive judgement & possibility (also, second mixed conditional) 
   *If she had been here, we could have started already, and would have easily been there on time!*